# Lightning Web Component isn't available for Salesforce Scheduler Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow, lightning-scheduler

I've created a Lightning Web Component with a target of `lightning__FlowScreen` but it isn't available in the Components list when building a screen for a **Salesforce Scheduler Flow**.

It *is* available on a standard **Screen Flow**.

**itemSelection.js-meta.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Item Selection</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="items" type="apex://ItemSelectionRequest[]" role="inputOnly" />
            <property name="selectedItemId" type="String" role="outputOnly" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Update: I've narrowed the problem down to the `apex://…` property type. If I remove that, or change it to `String`, the component becomes available. Is this a bug? I can't see any documentation about it not working in Salesforce Scheduler Flows anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Lightning Web Component with a target lightning__FlowScreen and type="apex" isn't available in the Components list when building a screen for a Salesforce Scheduler Flow at this time

It is available when building a screen for a standard Screen Flow.

This is a platform bug W-11546326 and unfortunately there is no workaround at this time. The Salesforce Scheduler Flow template is missing the Apex datatype in the variables configuration causing the issue