# Calling Scheduler Screen Flow from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-scheduler

I was trying to develop LWC that retrieves Service Resource Id and pass it to `Generate Appointment Invitation` flow, which is called it from `<lightning-flow>` tag.

[Salesforce help: Generate an Appointment Invitation URL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_generate_appnt_invitation_url.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)

However, I passed two input variables the following, however got the error below.

[image]

```js
    flowInputVariables = [
        {
            name: 'recordId',
            type: 'String',
            value: this.recordId,
        },
        {
            name: 'InvitationURLPrefix',
            type: 'String',
            value: this.InvitationURLPrefix,
        },
    ];
```

`recordId` is successfully passed from Parent LWC.

```html
<template>
    <!-- Invoke a Screen flow in LWC -->
    <span> test2 {recordId} </span>
    <lightning-flow
        flow-api-name={flowApiName}
        flow-input-variables={flowInputVariables}
        onstatuschange={handleFlowStatusChange}>
    </lightning-flow>
</template>
```

I am not sure why this is not working, but I found the post similar to this: [Lightning Web Component isn't available for Salesforce Scheduler Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381187/lightning-web-component-isnt-available-for-salesforce-scheduler-flow)

Passing `recordId` value to flow debugging just works.
So I suspect caling Scheduler Screen Flow is not worked from LWC?

Comment: Hi @mkzyk, are you retrieving the recordId from within your LWC or is that being passed into that component as an attribute? I suspect the issue may actually be required to when that recordId is available compared to when the flow is being passed the attributes.

Comment: Hi @CallumMacErlich, thanks for your comment. `recordId` variable is passed from Parent Component as @api variable.

Comment: Would you be able to try hiding the <lightning-flow> until the recordId has definitely been populated? Something like ``` <template if:true={recordIdPopulated}> ``` in your HTML file, and a getter method in your JS file to return if that is ready? That will just confirm if it is what I suspect.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Yes, I did use `<template if:true>` to call a flow, but finally I figured this out. I passed `recordId` from Parent Component as `<c-child-component record-id={recordId}></c-child-component>`, in that case the `recordId` variable must be @api (public) on child component, I don't know this is whether feature specification, public variable can not be passed into a flow as `flow-input-variables`, I changed calling a flow from parent and passed `recordId` directly, it has been worked! (but when I changed `recordId` variable as @api, it does not work.)